# flags passed to c compiler only in NDK

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk

If I want to pass compile flags to c compiler only in NDK, what should I do?
We know setting LOCAL_CFLAGS will impact not only C source file, but also c++ 
source files…

Answer (score 0):

I'm using combination of LOCAL_CFLAGS and LOCAL_CPPFLAGS. Setting flags for both C and C++ source files in LOCAL_CFLAGS and negating necessary flags in LOCAL_CPPFLAGS. Didn't find better solution and works for my simple use.

Comment: I have not been able to negate a '-std=c99' flag in LOCAL_CXXFLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

`LOCAL_CONLYFLAGS` works in AOSP, hopefully it works in the NDK as well.

It's useful for things like `-std=c99`, which doesn't apply to C++.